# ERROR: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.'

Tags: c#, forms

I need to find where DataReader is open or something that explains this error and resolves, please help me I've tried everything !!

I already closed all the connections of the code. I already tried using multipleactiveresultsets in my connection.

```
namespace Aula05
{
    public partial class frmImportar : Form
    {

        #region Eventos

        private void btnProcurar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ofdAbrir.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtNome.Text = ofdAbrir.FileName;
                btnImportar.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void btnImportar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Importar();
            MessageBox.Show("Importação realizada com sucesso");
        }

        #endregion

        #region Métodos

        public frmImportar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Importar()
        {
            StreamReader leitor = new StreamReader(txtNome.Text);
            String linha = String.Empty;

            while (!leitor.EndOfStream)
            {
                linha = leitor.ReadLine();

                String[] dados = linha.Split(';');
                string nome = dados[0];
                string cpf = dados[1];
                string idunidade = dados[2];


                Conexao c = new Conexao();

                c.Abrir();

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from colaborador where CPF = @CPFC");
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("CPFC", cpf));

                MySqlDataReader leia = c.Pesquisar(cmd);

                if (leia.Read())
                {
                    cmd = new MySqlCommand("update colaborador set Nome = @NomeC, idUnidade = @idUnidadeC where CPF = @CPFC");
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("NomeC", nome));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("idUnidadeC", cpf));
                    c.Executar(cmd);                   
                    c.Fechar();
                    leia.Close(); 
                }
                else

                {                    
                    cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into colaborador values (default, @NomeC, @CPFC, @idUnidadeC");
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("NomeC", nome));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("CPFC", cpf));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("idUnidadeC", idunidade));
                    c.Executar(cmd);
                    c.Fechar();
                    leia.Close();

                }                

            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Explaining the code: I need to get an excel table, check if cpf (something like id) already exists in the sql database, if I already have in the database I need to change the data, if not including the client in the database.

Comment: Which line of code gives the error?

Comment: i dont know, just there's a datareader open but dont know where it is

Comment: If you debug your code, you will know which line us breaking the code.

Answer (score 0):

Close `leia` before executing another command.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from colaborador where CPF = @CPFC");
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("CPFC", cpf));

MySqlDataReader leia = c.Pesquisar(cmd);
leia.Close();
```

If not works then

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from colaborador where CPF = @CPFC");
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("CPFC", cpf));

MySqlDataReader leia = c.Pesquisar(cmd);
if(leia.Read()) {
    leia.close();
    // DO YOUR OPERATIONS HERE
}
else {
    leia.close();
    // DO YOUR OPERATIONS HERE
}
```

Comment: If its a valid answer, then accept it. It'll help others to decide as a solution

Answer (score 0):

Having to close connections manually is errors prone.

Removing the possibility of forgetting to close resources is to implement the database operations with the `using` block.

You can read the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement),in a nutshell the using block will dispose resources for you once we are out of their scope.

```
public void Importar()
{
    StreamReader leitor = new StreamReader(txtNome.Text);
    String linha = String.Empty;

    while (!leitor.EndOfStream)
    {
        linha = leitor.ReadLine();

        String[] dados = linha.Split(';');
        string nome = dados[0];
        string cpf = dados[1];
        string idunidade = dados[2];


        using(Conexao c = new Conexao())
        {
            c.Abrir();
            using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from colaborador where CPF = @CPFC"))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@CPFC", cpf));
                using(MySqlDataReader leia = c.Pesquisar(cmd))
                {
                    if (leia.Read())
                    {
                        using(MySqlCommand updateCmd = new MySqlCommand("update colaborador set Nome = @NomeC, idUnidade = @idUnidadeC where CPF = @CPFC"))
                        {
                            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@NomeC", nome));
                            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@idUnidadeC", idunidade));
                            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@CPFC", cpf));
                            c.Executar(updateCmd);                   
                        }
                        else
                        {                    
                            using(MySqlCommand insertCmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into colaborador values (default, @NomeC, @CPFC, @idUnidadeC"))
                            {
                                insertCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@NomeC", nome));
                                insertCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@idUnidadeC", idunidade));
                                insertCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@CPFC", cpf));
                                c.Executar(insertCmd);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the code is better structured, shows intend and above all I dont need to worry about closing each and every connection.

Please note that you have made some errors with your SQL parameters( I have fixed them). You use them with the @ sign but declared them without it.

So in the first if block when trying to execute the command - @CPFC in the query is not defined as you have declared the parameter as CPFC.